# Quantum mechanics of projectile motion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian-formalism

In classical mechanics, the Lagrangian of a particle undergoing projectile motion without drag in a constant gravitational field is $$L=\frac{1}{2}m\left(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2\right)-mgy.$$ Performing a Legendre transform on this gives the Hamiltonian, which is $$H=\frac{1}{2m}\left(p_x^2+p_y^2\right)+mgy.$$
Classically the problem amounts to solving for the trajectory of the particle, which can be done trivially from calculating Hamilton's equations for the above Hamiltonian, and it is $$p_x(t)=p_{x}(0),\quad x(t)=x(0)+\frac{p_{x}(0)}{m}t$$
$$p_y(t)=p_{y}(0)-mgt,\quad y(t)=y(0)+\frac{p_{y}(0)}{m}t-\frac{1}{2}gt^2,$$ which gives that the trajectory is a parabola, as is well known.

In quantum mechanics, by quantising the above Hamiltonian by substituting the dynamical variables by operators, we get that the Hamiltonian operator is $$\hat{H}=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \left( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\right)+mg\hat{y},$$ where the transformations $\mathbf{p} \rightarrow \hat{\mathbf{p}}=-i \hbar \nabla$, $y \rightarrow \hat{y}$ and $x \rightarrow \hat{x}$ were used. With all of this the Schrödinger equation for this system is $$i\hbar \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \left( \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}+ \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial y^2}\right)+mgy\psi.$$ Now my question is, what can be said about the quantum mechanical behaviour of this system? How to solve the above Schrödinger equation? Are there any practical applications of this quantum analogue of projectile motion? Also, how it can be shown that the expectation value of position and momentum lead to the well-known classical trajectory equations?

Comment: Did you try to solve for the energy eigenstates of this Hamiltonian? The form of the energy eigenstates is essentially what tells us about the quantum mechanical behavior of the system. As far as the applications go, this is essentially the same Hamiltonian as one would get for the motion of an electron in a homogeneous electric field.

Comment: http://www.physics.csbsju.edu/QM/fall.03.html

Comment: I don't think replacing classical observables with linear operators is called "Quantising"